# Mobile Standard Layout

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, pagelayoutassignment

We have a standard page layout associated with the recordtype on Account this page has about 80 fields.We want to use Salesforce1 mobile app so want to have a smaller version of it in the mobile app.But as far i have seen whatever the layout you have for the standard Salesforce   can only be used in the Salesforce1 too.Is there any way to create two different layouts like one for mobile and one for standard Salesforce? please advice.

Comment: Completely agree, and I invite you to vote for this idea : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxyTAAQ

Answer (score 2):

At this time, there is no possibility to make a different layout that is only used for mobile. The best practice recommendation is that you place most of the fields needed in a mobile context at the top in your page layout.

What you could do however is the following:

- create a visualforce page where you check if you are in the Salesforce1 context or not. You can check this by using the Salesforce1 navigation API. I have some sample code in my question here: [cancel URL for sforce.one.createRecord](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/cancel-url-for-sforce-one-createrecord)
- when in the Salesforce1 context, you could show your visualforce page where you decide what you want to show and how.
- when not in the Salesforce1 context, you can just redirect to the standard detail page of your record
- you then override the "view" button of your object to point to this visualforce page

The disadvantage is though that you would then have to maintain that visualforce page but it could be a solution if restructuring your page layout to better fit mobile isn't an option.

Comment: Maybe, it should be possible to switch the profile after login with apex?